# syntax issue with JS /HTML nesting quotations

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error: "missing ) after argument list" from firebug running this script. I attempted to us /' to nest the parameters in my window.open equation. Can anyone see what's wrong here?

```
onclick="getinfo(); setTimeout('window.open(/'checkout.php/', /'_self/', /'location=yes/', /'false/')',10000);"
```

Answer (score 2):

The forward slashes need to be back slashes

```
onclick="getinfo(); setTimeout('window.open(\'checkout.php\', \'_self\', \'location=yes\', \'false\')',10000);"
```

Answer (score 2):

Quotes should be escaped with backslashes.

(Yet another reason to try and be a bit more unobtrusive with your JavaScript!)

Answer (score 1):

As [Dave said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719472/syntax-issue-with-js-html-nesting-quotations/7719503#7719503), move the code out of the `onclick` and it will be much clearer:

```
onclick="myFunction()"

<script>
function myFunction() {
  getinfo();
  setTimeout(function() {
      window.open('checkout.php', '_self', 'location=yes', 'false')
    },
    10000);
}
</script>
```

You could be more unobtrusive that this too, but this is a good start and it solves your quoting problem.